# Basic Pygame Program Not Executing

Tags: python, 2d, pygame, graphic

Typed in this pygame code for an animation test, I was expecting some errors, but the program simply won't execute:

First part imports modules

```
import sys
import os
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
```

Initialize pygame

```
pygame.init ()
```

classes to load sprite image files, and later, sound

```
class Processes (object):
    @staticmethod
    def load_image (imagefile):
        image = pygame.image.load (imagefile)
        return image, image.get_rect ()
```

Sprite class

```
class Sprite (pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__ (self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__ (self)
        self.image, self.rect = Processes.load_image ('frame1.jpg')
```

Simple animation function -- To make life easier

```
    def animation (self, key_event):
        if key_event == K_DOWN:
            self.rect.centery = self.rect.centery - 10

        if key_event == K_UP:
            self.rect.centery = self.rect.centery + 10

        if key_event == K_RIGHT:
            self.rect.centerx = self.rect.centerx + 10

        if key_event == K_LEFT:
           self.rect.centerx = self.rect.centerx - 10

        return self.rect
```

Main function:

```
def main ():
    mecha = Sprite ()
    allsprites = pygame.sprite.RenderPlain ((mecha, ))
```

Game loop:

```
while True:
    Surface = pygame.display.set_mode ((400, 400))
    pygame.display.set_caption ('Animation Test')

    for event in pygame.event.get ():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            mecha.animation (event.key)

        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit ()
            sys.exit (0)


    allsprites.draw (Surface)
    pygame.display.update ()
```

Here is the actual 'error'

```
C:/Khan's Family/python/Bunnies Vs. Zombies/BvZ_Animtest.py
```

Now here is the output:

```
(Nothing)

C:/Khan's Family/python/Bunnies Vs. Zombies
```

There is no output, and that's my problem.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "won't execute"?  If you run from the command line, do you get any output; does the program hang?  What happens if you put a print() in your main loop?  One thing you should do is move your `set_mode` call out of your game loop.

Comment: Next time, don't put in the parts that are not code.  It makes it extremally hard to copy the program into a window so you can run it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

What happens in pygame when it has an error is what I think you mean by "Won't excecute."  You have to spam click the x button to close it, and the error will show up in the shell.  On this paticular program, the error is:

```
File "C:/Python32/projects/deletable.py", line 45, in <module>
    allsprites.draw (Surface)
NameError: name 'allsprites' is not defined
```

You can deal with the problems yourself, but that is what happened.

Comment: The problem is that it's not actually showing an error, but when I run the program from the command line, it won't run.                                        @PygameNerd: But allsprites is defined as the RenderPlain class.

Comment: @user1792990 Are you using python 3.2 or python 2.7?

Comment: I'm using python 2.7. But never mind, I figured out the problem. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I made the stupid mistake of defining the 'main' function, but never executing it. Thanks guys.